# Subring of real numbers that contains $\frac12 $

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find, with explanation, the small subring, S of a ring R, real numbers such that $\frac12 \in $ S.

Obviously Q, the rational numbers is a ring that contains $\frac12$. Is there a smaller subring?

Comment: Yes. The smallest subring containing 1/2 is the set that contains 1/2 and is closed under addition and multiplication. You should be able to figure out a general formula for rational numbers of this form.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the subring $S$ is called the ring of [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational). The question is asking you to prove that $S$ is indeed a ring containing $\frac12$, and that every ring containing $\frac12$ contains $S$.